# How to create custom dialog in Cypress

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, alert, cypress

I am working with a custom command in cypress that pauses the test and opens a window.prompt() that asks the user for some input and adds it to the mochawesome report with the addcontext command. However, I want to create my own custom dialog that has a textbox and two buttons - pass/fail (basically a combination of window.prompt() and window.confirm()). Is there some way I can create my own html element and display it in cypress?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I injected html into the dom through Cypress.$(body).append(... and then accessed the elements through jquery. I used waitUntil and cy.focused as well as the regular jquery button focus events to pause execution of the test and resume after the pause or fail buttons were pressed.